# What is the most physically robust USB connector for PCB?

Tags: pcb, usb, connector

Of the different types of USB connector that can be fitted to a PCB, which is the most physically robust type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would definitely be USB B. It's available thru-hole, and typically has large thru-hole mounting lugs too. It's also several times the size of micro or mini.

Comment: I would tend to agree, larger through hole is better. The A type sockets (as you find on a PC), can suffer from bending of the contact pins however. We had a machine in the lab for QA testing USB devices, and it constantly had devices inserted and removed. We destroyed a few of the USB ports in the space of a year or so.

Answer (score 1):

I think that generally through hole parts are more robust than surface mount parts. However USB micro-B is not available in through-hole packages.